# Using volume for a person

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

**Situation**: I am on a zoom call and could hear the other person, but the sound of his voice is too low causing difficulty in listening.
Is the sentence `Your volume is too low` correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is probably understandable.  It could be interpreted as "the volume of your microphone is too low",

In terms of zoom etiquette, it is easier to describe your problem, and not the inferred reason for the problem. You *think* that the volume is too low, but what if it is already turned up to the maximum?  Perhaps the actual problem something else (eg coffee mug on the laptop microphone.  I've done that!).  You can describe the problem from your point of view as "I can't hear you (clearly)"